# Javascript assign only intersection of source to target object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two object, and I want to update the target object values from source, but only the values which exists in the target already.

```
const target = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: {
        c_a: 3,
        c_b: 4,
    }
}

const source = {
    a: 10,
    c: {
        c_a: 30,
        c_d: 50,
    },
    d: 60
}

const result = assignOnlyIntersection(target, source);

JSON.stringify(result)

// {
//    a: 10,
//    b: 2,
//    c: {
//        c_a: 30,
//        c_b: 4
//    }
// }
```

Is there a good way in **ES6** for this? If not, does lodash has a feature for this? If not how can it be solved in a nice way?

Answer (score 3):

A simple recursive function will do:

```
function assignOnlyIntersection(target, source) {
    if (Object(target) !== target || Object(source) !== source)
        return source;
    for (const p in source)
        if (p in target)
            target[p] = assignOnlyIntersection(target[p], source[p]);
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through keys of `target` object, check if there is same key on `source` object and if so, replace the value. You also need recursion if you find an object on the way.

Something like this could do the job:

```js
const target = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { c_a: 3, c_b: 4 }};
const source = { a: 10, c: { c_a: 30, c_d: 50 }, d: 60 };

function assignOnlyIntersection(t, s) {
    Object
        .keys(s)
        .filter(k => k in t)
        .forEach(k => {
           if (typeof t[k] === 'object') {
               assignOnlyIntersection(t[k], s[k]);
           } else {
               t[k] = s[k];
           }
    });
    
    return t;
}

const result = assignOnlyIntersection(target, source);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Also note that if you want to support replacing with falsy values like `0` or `''`, you will need to check for existence with `typeof t[k] !== 'undefined'`.

As @ghybs noted, if you want to also support replacing with `undefined` values, you will need to check via [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) `k in t` instead.

Comment: What if `t[k]` is false?

Comment: I was just adding note about that :]

Comment: Better indeed! But still, `t` could have a `k` key that is still `undefined`. `k in t` should be what you are looking for. Or `t.hasOwnProperty`

Comment: True, added note about that too.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach by checking for objects.

```js
function deepAssign(target, source) {
    Object.keys(source).forEach(function (k) {
        var objectCount = [source, target]
                .map(o => o[k])
                .map(o => o && typeof o === 'object')
                .map(Boolean)
                .reduce((a, b) => a + b)

        if (!(k in target) || objectCount === 1) {
            return;
        }
        if (objectCount === 2) {
            return deepAssign(target[k], source[k]);
        }
        target[k] = source[k];
    });
    return target;
}

var source = { a: 10, c: { c_a: 30, c_d: 50, }, d: 60 },
    target = { a: 1, b: 2, c: { c_a: 3, c_b: 4, } };

console.log(deepAssign(target, source));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

another ES6 approach

**non-mutative:**

```
const intersector = (target = {}, source = {}) => {
  return Object.keys(source).reduce((acc, prop) => {
    if (target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null) {
        acc[prop] = intersector(target[prop], source[prop]);
      }
      else {
        acc[prop] = source[prop];
      } 
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

**mutative:**

```
const intersector = (target = {}, source = {}) => {
  return Object.keys(source).reduce((acc, prop) => {
    if (target.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (typeof source[prop] === 'object' && source[prop] !== null) {
        acc[prop] = intersector(target[prop], source[prop]);
      }
      else {
        acc[prop] = source[prop];
      }
      target[prop] = acc[prop];
    }
    return acc;
  }, target);
};
```

Comment: Just realized you were asking to update the target. My answer doesn't mutate the target, but rather returns a new Object.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `Array.reduce()` and `Object.keys()` ES6 features to achieve this:

```js
let target = {
a: 1,
b: 2,
c: {
    c_a: 3,
    c_b: 4,
}
}

let source = {
a: 10,
c: {
    c_a: 30,
    c_d: 50,
},
d: 60
}

const assignOnlyIntersection = (sourceObj, targetObj) => {
return Object.keys(targetObj).reduce((intersection, key) => { 
    intersection[key] = (typeof targetObj[key] === 'object') ? assignOnlyIntersection(sourceObj[key], targetObj[key]) : sourceObj[key] || targetObj[key];
    return intersection; 
}, {})
}

target = assignOnlyIntersection(source, target);

console.log(target);
```